# CompizConfig Problems

Tags: unity, compiz, settings

I have installed CompizConfig on my computer and configured it to what I want. I'm using Cube with wallpaper enabled and four different wallpaper for each side of the cube.

Everything works fine until I boot or reboot. I get a black background instead, and have to go back in to compiz, disable wallpaper and them enable it again to restore the wallpaper.

How do I prevent this from happening when I shut down or reboot?